# debian10 unable to start mysql server

Tags: mysql, debian

system debian 10, installed mysql server through following steps：

1. dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.17-1_all.deb
2. apt-get update
3. apt-get install -y mysql-server
   and got

```
    2021-06-07T02:21:11.312176Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.25) initializing of server in progress as process 1838
    2021-06-07T02:21:11.325988Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
    2021-06-07T02:21:11.825707Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
    2021-06-07T02:21:13.160846Z 6 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
    Setting up mysql-server (8.0.25-1debian10) ...
    Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.28-10) ...
    root@a5cfe5ec0be9:/web_api# service mysql start
    mysql: unrecognized service
```

then my tried to use mysql ,i got

`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

i tried to strat the service , it was not found

```
mysql: unrecognized service
root@937f56df67cd:~# service mysqld start
mysqld: unrecognized service
```

the mysql was not found in following folder:

```
/etc/init.d# ls
hwclock.sh  procps  ssh
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Debian 10 too, and wanted to install `mysql` (to use with Wordpress).

The installation was a mess, I ended up using `MariaDB`, which fully satisfied my requirements. MariaDB is in the Debian stable repositories and works fine with Wordpress, without changing anything.

If you want to give a try:

```
sudo apt install default-mysql-server
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

It's not exactly fixing your issue, but this workaround may help you.

Comment: exactly，mariadb is much easier to install. but it does not support cast type as JSON, so I have to use the original mysql.......

Comment: Ah, I understand now. What gives the command `sudo systemctl status mysql`?

Comment: I did a research with `apt search mysql`  and noticed a package, `mysql-sandbox` in the Debian stable repositories:

"*MySQL Sandbox is a tool that installs one or more MySQL servers within seconds, easily, securely, and with full control*". I didn't test it but it looks promising. See https://packages.debian.org/buster/mysql-sandbox

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, systemctl does not work; mysql-sandbox looks like a good idea, but I encountered issue when using it, still trying...